# RDP works fine on a wired connection, but over wireless it throws error

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, wireless-networking, remote-desktop

RDP works fine on a wired connection, but over wireless it throws the following error:

"Remote Desktop cannot find the remote computer type the name or address again or contact admin"

Using a windows XP laptop to connect to a windows 7 workstation.  I've attempted to connect with both name and IP.

Any troubleshooting steps you would try?

Comment: Have you looked at the firewall settings?

Comment: Are you trying to use the same IP for the wired connection to the computer when you use the WiFi, You will be assigned a different IP for each one

Answer (score 1):

Can you ping the computer you are trying to RDP into while over the wireless?

At my work, we have our wireless split up into two categories (SSID's). One for general use and another for Accounting/IT. The general wireless is setup to only allow traffic to route out to the internet and to the printers. The 2nd SSID allows all traffic to route back internally (servers, computers, and printers) as well as out to the internet. So, it might be a route configuration in the Wireless Access Points and/or Primary Router.